# non standard git command

Tags: git, gerrit

I have few command for which  I did not find any official document of git site.

```
1) git cl presubmit
2) git cl upload
3) git cl try
```

How they are related to standard git? Is these command related google's chromium project only,

Comment: http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/tools/depot_tools/README.git-cl possibly related?

Answer (score 1):

These are custom subcommands. The easiest way to create one is:

1. Create a script
2. Name it `git-something`
3. Put the script in a place where git can find it, i.e your path
4. Run it using `git name`

As the [README](http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/tools/depot_tools/README.git-cl) indicates, the scripts are written in Python.

Comment: I guess the question wasn't about what they are or how to make them, but if they are standard to git or only related to that one project. The answer would be "they are related to that project only".